# Error inserting a new entity into the database because it conflicts with a duplicate key value

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink

Im trying to create CRUD test to show my JPA program works but it is giving me strange error when i create a new entity and commit it to the database. 
The Table supplier have only one contraint and that is a unique index that is autogenerated.
i will post the classes first then what i tried to do with them

Here is the SQL for the table and contraints

---

### --  DDL for Table SUPPLIER

```
CREATE TABLE SUPPLIER 
(   SUPPLIERID INTEGER NOT NULL GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY, 
COMPANYNAME VARCHAR(40), 
CONTACTNAME VARCHAR(30), 
CONTACTTITLE VARCHAR(30), 
ADDRESS VARCHAR(60), 
CITY VARCHAR(15), 
POSTALCODE VARCHAR(10), 
COUNTRY VARCHAR(15), 
PHONE VARCHAR(24), 
FAX VARCHAR(24)
);
```

---

### --  Constraints for Table SUPPLIER

```
ALTER TABLE SUPPLIER ALTER SUPPLIERID NOT NULL;

ALTER TABLE SUPPLIER ALTER COMPANYNAME NOT NULL;

ALTER TABLE SUPPLIER ADD CONSTRAINT PK_SUPPLIER PRIMARY KEY (SUPPLIERID);
```

This is my suppliers Primary key:

```
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "SUPPLIERID")
private Integer supplierid;
```

So first i create the entity and add it to my entitymanager

```
  Supplier sup = new Supplier("Test","Test","Test","Test","Test","Test","Test","Test","Test");
  em.persist(p);
```

Then i save it

```
public void Save() {

    em.getTransaction().begin();  
    em.getTransaction().commit();

}
```

And then i get the error below even thought the only constraint that can be broken is 2 identical pk but those are auto generated.

I know that my setup works because my 2 other tests ( inserting other new entities works fine).
 I also close and reopen connection between each test.

[EL Warning]: 2014-09-09 17:17:33.67--UnitOfWork(1407675409)--Exception [EclipseLink-4002]           (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.1.v20130918-f2b9fc5): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: The statement was aborted because it would have caused a duplicate key value in a unique or primary key constraint or unique index identified by 'PK_SUPPLIER' defined on 'SUPPLIER'.
Error Code: -20001
Call: INSERT INTO SUPPLIER (ADDRESS, CITY, COMPANYNAME, CONTACTNAME, CONTACTTITLE, COUNTRY, FAX, PHONE, POSTALCODE) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
    bind => [9 parameters bound]
Query: InsertObjectQuery(Peristency.Supplier[ supplierid=null ])

Comment: So what part of "duplicate key" is unclear?  The database already has row with the matching key.  `GenerationType.IDENTITY` means the underlying database is required to generate the key.  What does the `CREATE TABLE` look like, and what is the underlying database?  If you didn't set up the database to generate a unique key you can get this error.

Comment: The entity im inserting does not exsist. 
Ive added the SQL

Comment: I'm not well acquainted with eclipselink but this part looks fishy `Query: InsertObjectQuery(Peristency.Supplier[ supplierid=null ])` Seems like somehow eclipselink thinks you're trying to insert with a null id.

Comment: What does the constructor for `Supplier` look like? Are you setting an explicit value for `SUPPLIERID`? If so, what does your persistence layer do in this case?  I know PostgreSQL would use the value you provided and not generate a new one.

Comment: @JimGarrison
The constructor only sets some String values i do nothing with the pk or anything else.

Comment: @Taylor
I am not very experienced either in any jpa but it seems like that Peristency.Supplier[ supplierid=null ] is the "toString()" called on a entity by default

Answer (score 0):

The save method irritates me a little. Like it is written above, it performs an empty transaction, doesn't it? Shouldn't it be something like this:

```
public void Save() {
    ...
    em.getTransaction().begin();  
    ...
    Supplier sup = new Supplier("Test","Test","Test","Test","Test","Test","Test","Test","Test");
    em.persist(p);
    ...
    em.getTransaction().commit();
    ...
}
```

Could it be, that the coding for the question has been shortened too much, thus scrumbling the picture? Could you provide us please with the complete coding from starting the whole transaction until committing?

I remember once a while, I had a similar problem. Main point was, that I tried to persist twice in one transaction - and that was not possible - complaining about a duplicated key problem. May be that this is a hint for your case.

Comment: You are right i have chopped it up. 

My architecture idea was to add objects to the entity manager with persist() or merge() accordingly. Then commit the transaction when i needed to


i have tried cooking it down to 

`db.em.getTransaction().begin();  
   
Supplier sup = new   Supplier("Test","Test","Test","Test","Test","Test","Test","Test","Test");

    db.em.persist(sup);
    db.em.getTransaction().commit();`

But i get the same error. 

i think it might be how i do the constructor

Answer (score 0):

Okay after alot of Wall to face action i have found the cause of my problem

If you try to commit(entitymanager.getTransaction.commit()) a entity with a null pk to the database it wont work even if the database is supposed to provide the id.

What i had to do everytime i need a new object in a state where it can be saved to the db

```
 public void addEmployee(Employee p) {
     em.getTransaction().begin();
     em.persist(p);
     //Doesn't have an id
     System.out.println(p.getEmployeeid());
     em.flush();
     //now it has an id!
     System.out.println(p.getEmployeeid());
     em.getTransaction().commit();
}
```

Then later i can merge and commit at my leasure but i feel like i made a ineffecient solution with the database transaction i have.

Comment: you don't need `em.flush()`.

Comment: begin the transaction -> merge/persist -> commit
This is the right way and it is not inefficient. otherwise is meaningless